# E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "All": syntax error

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, syntax-error, android-sqlite

I am new to app development andam trying to build an app that searches a database table called "All" but keep getting this error:

> E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "All": syntax error
>
> Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
>       Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
>         (near "All": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT Phrase FROM All)

I think it must be a problem with my database setup but can't find the fault.

Here is my code:

```
public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME="DoYouGetMeDoc.db";
    private static final int DB_VER=1;
    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);
    }

    public List<Items> getall(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        String[] sqliteSelect={"Phrase","Description","Example", "Chapter"};
        String tableName="All";
        qb.setTables(tableName);
        Cursor cursor = qb.query(db,sqliteSelect,null,null,null,null,null);
        List<Items> results = new ArrayList<>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Items items = new Items();
                items.setPhrase(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Phrase")));
                items.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Description")));
                items.setExample(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Example")));
                items.setChapter(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Chapter")));
                results.add(items);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return results;
    }

    public List<String> getPhrases(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        String[] sqliteSelect={"Phrase"};
        String tableName="All";
        qb.setTables(tableName);
        Cursor cursor = qb.query(db,sqliteSelect,null,null,null,null,null);
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                results.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Phrase")));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return results;

    }

    public List<Items> getPhrasesbyPhrase(String phrase)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        String[] sqliteSelect={"Phrase","Description","Example","Chapter"};
        String tableName="All";
        qb.setTables(tableName);
        Cursor cursor = qb.query(db,sqliteSelect,"Phrase like ?",new String[]{"%"+phrase+"%"},null,null,null);
        List<Items> results = new ArrayList<>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Items items = new Items();
                items.setPhrase(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Phrase")));
                items.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Description")));
                items.setExample(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Example")));
                items.setChapter(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Chapter")));
                results.add(items);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return results;
    } }
```

in short, my app should allow the user to search the database using a search bar I set up in my MainActivity.xml but every time I try and open the app it keeps crashing.

I am completely stumped and would be really grateful for some advice.

Update:
I changed the table name from "All" too "FullBook" and am now getting this error:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: FullBook
```

Comment: Hi Rehman, ALL is a reserved keyword in SQLLITE (see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).  I would try re-naming your table then trying again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ALL` is a keyword (reserved word) for SQLite and all (I believe) rdms's 
and you can't use it as the name of a table.  
Here you can see all the reserved words of SQLite: 
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html 
If you insist to use it, you can enclose it in square brackets like `[All]`.

Comment: I changed the title of the table to "FullBook" but now am getting an new error

Comment: E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: FullBook

Comment: Uninstall the app from the emulator/device. Copy in the assets folder a new version of the db containing the new table with the new name and start all over again.